# VB .NET run without form and without UAC when /q argument passed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm VERY new at VB .NET and have recently downloaded MS Visual Studio Express 2012. I'm trying to design an application to replace a VBScript I created and can't find the answer to Two of the main design phase features I require so I apologize ahead of time for my ignorance.

I'm trying to create an application to edit the configuration parameters of an existing application I support. the configurations are edited in both the Files System and in the Windows Registry.

I'm looking for a way to pass a "/q" or "/quiet" and allow the application to run silently. I have developed the program far enough to edit the options in the form and save them. I can run code (so far only messages displaying the options) from the start configuration button from a "Windows Form Application".

I'm also needing to make sure that when running silently the application does not need UAC elevation. In the original VBScript  I need to elevate UAC when editing the Windows Registry.

I know this is a lot to ask for with my current knowledge level. But I'm still in the design stage and trying to learn fast and really need to know if this is even possible before I go too far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the original application required UAC elevation to edit the registry then the new one will too. The level of access is on a per user basis not a per application basis so unless you run the application as a different user you will have the same problem with your new application.

As to running without showing the form you will need to edit Main something like this:

```
 <STAThread()> _
 Shared Sub Main()
    ' Read the arguments    
    ' Starts the application.
    if (argument == "/q" or argument == "/quiet") then
        ' Edit the other program configurations here
    else
        Application.Run(New Form1())
    End if
 End Sub
```

You can call a [version of `Run(ApplicationContext )` that doesn't show a form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157901.aspx), but as the starts the message loop you'd still need some way of actually editing the other program's configuration, perhaps in response to key strokes.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I'm looking for, but I suppose that's where my ignorance is. I know there's a Sub Main (everything I can find says there must be one). The problem I have is where to find it in Visual Studio 2012 to edit it. Honestly I'm almost wishing I could freehand this project. I have set Sub Main as the startup object but even showing all files I'm having trouble locating it. Can I just create it? And where should I do so?

Comment: Or should I just create it as a console application and add in the Windows form?

Comment: Thanks!! That actually worked great when I created a module for it. I was unable to declare as shared but it functions great. how would I pass the Boolean state I'm creating to the form or to other modules where I'm thinking of putting the functions. I would want to get this to the functions to suppress errors and prompts.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I was able to finally understand it. thanks for all your help.